# http header rel=“canonical” through htaccess for dynamic content

Tags: php, htaccess, apache, joomla3

I have a large number of URLS where I need to specify rel="canonical", The URL structure is like:

`example.c.o.m/abcd?q=ccccc&location=ffff&x=pp&y=qq`

I need to strip the last two parameters `(&x=pp&y=qq)` and show `example.com/abcd?q=ccccc&location=ffff` as my canonical link in the header.

I have this as [moz reference](http://moz.com/blog/htaccess-file-snippets-for-seos) and tried various ways with *mod_RewriteRule*. I'm looking for either a htaccess solution or that of one that works with Joomla CMS.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up [canonical links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) is done via the content and not the rewrite. Since you are using Joomla this can be easily achieved by using various plugins that allow you to manually  set the formatting of the URLS via rewrite and it'll add the canonical links to your dymanic content.

You can use [SH404SEF](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef/10134) to do this as well as many others on [Joomla's vast plugin library](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/sef) that you can explore, other methods include [editing the template files](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aModifying_a_Joomla!_Template) and adding custom code to do this but of course you'd need to learn the Joomla handles in order to do so. If you want more in depth information then I recommend you ask your question on the [Beta Joomla Stack](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/users/login) or the [official Joomla Forums](http://forum.joomla.org/).